# Android: Memory Analyzer Tool: Determin where objects are allocated

Tags: android, eclipse-memory-analyzer

We have what appears to be a memory leak on some Android devices (Nexus 5, 5.1.1).

We have gotten some memory dumps and run them through the Eclipse Memory Analyzer tool and it seems that there is an increasing number of byte-arrays which are not being cleared.

[image]

The Tab on the right shows the state at app start and tab on the left shows after 20 or so app loops. (The app will eventually cause a oom if left running its loop)

How do I use the tool to track down where these byte arrays are being allocated?

Comment: Search you class name check who is keeping reference of that class.

Left top- Class Name is their (Search you activity or fragment  and that look into details by clicking)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've gone a bit "hardcore".

Why don't you go with [Allocation tracker](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-allocation.html)? You can see where precisely the object was instantiated.

[image]

---

### Here's [Allocation tracker walkthrough](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/allocation-tracker-walkthru.html).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. 
I had a look but it looks to me this tool keeps a track of all the allocations in the test period and not just the current objects.
This still leaves it hard to figure out exactly which byteArrays are not being cleared.